# BBEdit progressively update command line

Tags: bbedit

Is it possible to use the BBEdit command line tool and update it progressively.

Example: `(echo -n "foo"; sleep 3; echo " bar") | bbedit`
This will appear after 3 seconds, but I want it to display `foo` and then wait and display `foo bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If BBEdit is set to reload files when they change, you can create a temporary file, open it, and write to it with an interval of 3 seconds.

```
file=`mktemp -t file`
bbedit $file
(echo "foo";sleep 3;echo " bar")>>$file
```

I haven't found a way to pipe directly to BBEdit so that it updates after 3 seconds.